# Margin increases size of other divs

Tags: html, css, css-grid, margin

So I have been learning the grid system and have encountered something that is very confusing to me. When I want to give margin-bottom to one of the div's for some reason it will increase the height of the div that it next to it. Any idea's on what I'm missing out here? So I give .box-2 a margin-bottom of 100px and whilst it creates 100px of space at the bottom, .box-1 that is next to it will increase in height.

```css
.container
{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr
}

.item
{
  border:2px solid;
  text-align:center;
}

.box-1
{
  background-color:blue;
}

.box-2
{
  background-color:purple;
  margin-bottom:100px
}

.box-3
{
  background-color:orange;
}

.box-4
{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
<div class = "item box-1">
  <h1>One</h1>
</div>

<div class = "item box-2">
   <h1>Two</h1>
</div>
  

<div class = "item box-3">
   <h1>Three</h1>
</div>

<div class = "item box-4">
   <h1>Four</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you want something like masonry layout (look it up). What you are describing is the default behavior, that's just how grid is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you trying to achieve.

```css
.container
{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
}

.item
{
  border:2px solid;
  text-align:center;
}

.box-1
{
  background-color:blue;
  
}

.box-2
{
  background-color:purple;
  
 
}

.box-3
{
  background-color:orange;
  margin-bottom:100px;
}

.box-4
{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
  <div>
<div class = "item box-1">
  <h1>One</h1>
</div>

<div class = "item box-2">
   <h1>Two</h1>
</div>
   </div>
  
<div>
<div class = "item box-3">
   <h1>Three</h1>
</div>

<div class = "item box-4">
   <h1>Four</h1>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```